# How do I SELECT the ROW with Highest Value in a Query with SUM() and JOIN?

Tags: mysql, sql

My Query Here

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8bcf5a/20/0

```
SELECT i.id
     , i.mon 
     , i.item
     , SUM(v.value) value
  FROM items i
  LEFT 
  JOIN values v 
    ON v.item_id = i.id
 WHERE mon = 'Y'
 GROUP 
    BY i.id
 ORDER 
    BY v.value DESC;
```

I get all the rows with `mon = Y`, But I only want to get the Highest row with `mon = x` and `value = MAX`.

So instead of getting

```
id  mon     item    value
2   Y       C1      17
1   Y       C1      11
3   Y       C1      5
```

I want  to get

```
id  mon     item    value
2   Y       C1      17
```

**I can use `LIMIT 1`, But the Query would still fetch all the rows, So it is like hiding the problem.**

Because I don't want The query to fetch 1000 row If i had them with `mon = Y`, But only the row with `mon = Y` and `value = MAX`

I've tried something like

```
AND value = MAX(value)
```

or

```
AND value = TOP(value)
```

But ofcource it seems incorrect overall

Comment: "I can use LIMIT 1, But the Query would still fetch all the rows, So it is like hiding the problem."  I have no idea what the concern is here.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Isn't `LIMIT` applied after fetching the rows?

Comment: read this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/limit-optimization.html

Comment: @isaace Oh, I see this line `If you combine LIMIT row_count with ORDER BY, MySQL stops sorting as soon as it has found the first row_count rows of the sorted result` answers it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add a `LIMIT` clause to your query as follows:

```
  SELECT
  i.`id`,i.`mon` , i.`item`, SUM(v.`value`) AS value
  FROM `items` i
  LEFT JOIN `values` v ON v.`item_id` = i.`id`
  WHERE mon = 'Y'
  GROUP BY i.`id`
  ORDER BY v.`value` DESC
  LIMIT 1;
```

that will only return the first row (note I just added the last line).

Answer (score 0):

You're grouping the data on the original value on the table instead of the sum of rhe values. Try this:

```
 SELECT i.id
 , i.mon 
 , i.item
 , SUM(v.value) totalValue
 FROM items i
 LEFT 
 JOIN values v 
 ON v.item_id = i.id
 WHERE mon = 'Y'
 GROUP  BY i.id, i.mon , i.item
 ORDER  BY SUM( v.value) DESC
 LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Isn't it the same thing As if I just added `LIMIT 1` to my Query?

Comment: Not the same thing. Try naming the sum of the values to something other than `value` and use it in the group by clause. It won't work, because it is an alias. It worked in your case because the alias name you used coincides with the original name of the field your are renaming.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your clause:

```
AND value in (select MAX(value) from values)
```

intead of

```
AND value = MAX(value)
```

and include

```
AND rownum = 1
```